# jquery: concatenating with insertAfter()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Objective: When 'Submit' is clicked, add the contents of the textbox below the button into a h3 element.

So I made a variable `contents` which takes in the value from the textbox. When I click the submit button, it should insert the `h3` element with `contents` inside it. I'm not sure if it's something with concatenating in jquery or if there's something else I'm missing here. Apologies since I'm still new to jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var contents = $('#textInput').val();
  $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
    $("<h3>" + contents + "</h3>").insertAfter('#submitBtn');
  })
})
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the value of the text area *before* the button is clicked. You need to obtain it inside the event handler (notice that you may also need to use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on the event in case your button is submitting a form or similar):

```js
$(function() {
    $('#submitBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("<h3>" + $('#textInput').val() + "</h3>").insertAfter(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textInput"></textarea>
<button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @4castle No, it isn't. That will literally append an `<h3>` element to the `<button>`.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of `$(this).after(...`

Answer (score 0):

You have to take input inside the click handler

check this snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $('#submitBtn').click(function() {
     var contents = $('#textInput').val();
 
    $("<h3></h3>").insertAfter($(this)).html(contents);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textInput">

<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="submitbtn">
```

Hope it helps